# ifconfig packet count

Tags: linux-kernel, counter, linux-device-driver, ifconfig

if I type ifconfig i get packet for Tx and RX ...  where exactly the piece of code to increment this counter?
Is it in the network driver itself? or in the kernel ?

If possible please provide lxr link of the counter variable used.

Thx !

Comment: belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done in the individual network drivers.

Eg, for the `rtl8139too` driver, the TX count is incremented on line 1786 ([see here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/drivers/net/8139too.c#L1786)).

Answer (score 0):

ifconfig read the statistics off from procfs. The values found in proc is updated by the kernel and ultimately boils down to the drivers of the network card.